# Mapping the response data in RestKit

Tags: ios, iphone, restkit

I had used `restkit` in my project and i am trying to map the json data.

Response data format is from `json GET` webservice is :

```
    [
      {
         "Id":"XXXX",
         "detailId":"XXXX",
         "OriginalTitle":"XXXX"
      },
      {
         "Id":"XXXX,
         "detailId":"XXXX",
         "OriginalTitle":"XXXX"
       }
    ]
```

How can i map the data with any key.

Generally i use below to map

```
     RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
     [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"status":@"strStatus",
@"message":@"strMessage"}]; 

     [objectMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"***MyKeyfromAPI***" toKeyPath:@"MyArrayVariableInProject" withMapping:[***SomeModelClass*** mapping]]];
```

Error are something like :

```
[request=1.0424s mapping=0.0000s total=1.2667s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded." 
{Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: 
This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings., keyPath=null, DetailedErrors=(
)}}, keyPath=null, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded.}
```

but in the response i have any key for array.
How can i map this. Please help.

Comment: You can try addAttributeMappingsFromArray

Comment: @NaveenRamanathan thank you for the comment. But i dont have any key in the json. How can i manage it from addAttributeMappingsFromArray